# Diablo 3 adding second weapon is decreasing my overall damage ? Why is this?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am not a Diablo 3 expert so I just want to know why after adding a second weapon for my monk, my overall damage decreases ?!

Comment: What weapon?  What did you replace it with?  We're going to need to know more than just that it reduced your damage.

Comment: Excuse me, sorry for lack of information.
I have a monk, got a new dagger. But when I combine it with one of my old fist weapons, the overall damage decreases ! 
Let me be more specific. This new dagger gives me overall 42.0 k damage. When I add my fist weapon to it , the overall damage goes back to 37.9 k !!! Is it weird or am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dual wielding your damage is calculated by taking the average damage of both your weapons and adding 15% (if I recall correctly) of attack speed.
If one of your weapons is noticeably weaker than the other, your overall damage is going to drop.